# Prove that the number of ways to choose two things from a set of $n$ things is $n(n+1)/2$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, proof-writing

In other words, prove $${n \choose 2} =\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

I am attempting to solve this proof using combinatorics. I know that by definition, $${n \choose 2} = \frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!}$$

So equivalently $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n!}{2(n-2)!}$$

$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)!}{2(n-2)!}$$

$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

But how is this possible? I appreciate any input–thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is indeed

$$
\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}.
$$

You actually proved this above. There must be a misprint in the original question.

Otherwise, as you concluded, 
$$
\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\implies n=0.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was hoping there was some way this would work out, but as you explained it that makes sense. I just wish I didn't have to tell my professor that he made a typo in his textbook, lol.

Comment: I'm sure he'd appreciate your observant eye!